# Getting 404 when loading AngularJS scripts

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot

I just moved my working AngularJS project into a spring-boot configuration. Spring is not the issue because I am able to locate the index.html file and display "Test test test" in the browser which is written in that file. However all my scripts are returning the following:

[image: console]

In my index.html file I set the `base href`:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="SharpVision">
    <head>
        <base href="/PersonalSite/src/main/webapp/">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
```

My body in index.html

```
<body>
    Test Test test
        <ng-include src="'app/views/structure/navigation.tpl.html'"></ng-include>

        <ng-view autoscroll="true"></ng-view>

        <ng-include src="'app/views/structure/footer.tpl.html'"></ng-include >

        <!--Scripts-->
        <!--<script src="bower_components/masonry/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>-->
        <!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="assets/libs/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/masonry/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular-flexslider/angular-flexslider.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular-backstretch/ng-backstretch.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular-parallax/angular-parallax.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular-fitvids/angular-fitvids.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular-masonry/angular-masonry.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/momentjs/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/humanize-duration/humanize-duration.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular-timer/angular-timer.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/ng-progress/js/ngprogress.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular-gmaps/angular-google-maps.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/lodash/lodash.min.js"></script>
        <script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
        <script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
        <script src="app/app.directives.js"></script>
        <script src="app/app.routes.js"></script>
        <script src="app/app.controllers.js"></script>

    </body>
```

In my app.js file I set a constant:

```
app.constant('ROOT', '/PersonalSite/src/main/webapp/');
```

Now everything was working fine until I brought in boot. However I just set up a `InternalResourceViewResolver` to render the `index.html` which it did so spring-boot is doing its job. For some reason Angularjs cannot find its scripts even though it is given the correct paths to find them.

Directory:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a plunker? Or any other resource?

Comment: GIT, never heard of Plucker. I can sign up if plucker is your choice of collaboration.

Comment: Setting the base and the ROOT to src/main/webapp doesn't make much sense. Those are **source directories** where your build tool looks for files to construct your jar/war file. At runtime, those directories are irrelevant. Spring boot serves resources from the jar/war file. Not from source directories. Read http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content.

Comment: That would be wonderfull And its called Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/

Comment: try to set `base href` back to `/`

Comment: @Yerken that solved my issue.

Comment: @Dsafds thank you very much for introducing me to Plucker. I have solved the issue. I had to change my `href` to `/` in my `index.html` file